# Why cannot a column with a character-only column name be subsetted?

Tags: r, data.table

See the following example. Column subsetting is fine for all the other columns, but it doesn't work for `repeat` column.

```
library(data.table)

dtt <- fread(text = 'tx_name    tstart  tend    repeat  class_family
ENST00000001008.6   3115    3216    AluJb   SINE/Alu
ENST00000001008.6   3351    3489    MIRb    SINE/MIR
ENST00000001008.6   3534    3625    MIR3    SINE/MIR
ENST00000002125.9   1657    1948    AluSp   SINE/Alu
ENST00000002165.10  1800    2356    Tigger3b    DNA/TcMar-Tigger
ENST00000002596.6   2588    2693    MIRb    SINE/MIR')

> dtt[, .(tx_name, class_family)]
#               tx_name     class_family
# 1:  ENST00000001008.6         SINE/Alu
# 2:  ENST00000001008.6         SINE/MIR
# 3:  ENST00000001008.6         SINE/MIR
# ...

dtt[, .(tx_name, repeat)]
# Error: unexpected ')' in "dtt[, .(tx_name, repeat)"
```

Comment: because `repeat` is reserved keyword? `dtt[, .(tx_name, \`repeat\`)]` works fine. Same goes for `while`, `for` and many other names as well.

Comment: @RonakShah and of course the most used reserved word: `df` :) Or not reserved but a function...

Comment: @RonakShah, that sounds reasonable. `?reserved` said that "Reserved words outside quotes are always parsed to be references to the objects linked to in the ‘Description’, and hence they are not allowed as syntactic names". And a column name of `df` could be used normally although not recommended.

Comment: The problem with the `j` part in data.table that it both used for evaluation and for selecting (unquoted) columns. In your case it had to decide and I guess somewhere in data.tables source code, evaluation comes first.